# How to interact with a deployed contract in a script/task using hardhat-deploy

Tags: javascript, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a folder structure that looks like the following in my [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) project.

```
scripts/
└── enter.ts
deploy
└── 01_Deploy_Raffle.ts
```

After I deploy a contract using hardhat deploy, my other deploy script, I am able to get the address of recent deployments with the `get` command.

```js
const deployRaffle: DeployFunction = async function (
  hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment
) {
  const { deployments, getNamedAccounts, getChainId } = hre
  const { deploy, log, get } = deployments
```

However, when I use this outside the deploy folder, I seem to run into issues. Hardhat-deploy might not be saving the deployments when I run them to a local blockchain. So, I'll run `npx hardhat node` (which runs the scripts in my deploy folder), and then try my script outlined below:

```js
import { run, ethers, deployments } from 'hardhat'

async function main() {
  await run('compile')
  const { get } = deployments
  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
  const Raffle = await ethers.getContractFactory('Raffle')
  const RaffleDeployment = await get('Raffle')
  const raffle = new ethers.Contract(RaffleDeployment.address, Raffle.interface, accounts[0])
  console.log(raffle.s_entranceFee()) // this line errors
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: No deployment found for: Raffle
    at get (/Users/patrick/code/decentralized-raffle/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:150:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async main (/Users/patrick/code/decentralized-raffle/scripts/enter.ts:11:28)
```

So what's the best way to write a script with hardhat-deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common "gotcha" of hardhat deploy. You have to use `--network localhost` when running a script with your own hardhat node locally.

The default network is the `hardhat` network otherwise.

Comment: +1. In case people are wondering, the default network is usually just `hardhat` (the internal network that gets spun up) which is different from `localhost` if you run `npx hardhad node`. This can all be configured with `defaultNetwork ` as shown in https://hardhat.org/config/.

Comment: Nice, I updated the answer accordingly